# JQuery ajax call failing but the direct URL works

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a simple Jquery code which makes an ajax call to a php code.

$(document).ready(function(){

```
var $isbn = $('#isbn');
var $authorName = $('#authorName');
var $bookTitle = $('#bookTitle');

$('#searchButton').click(function(){

    var isbnValue = $isbn.val();
    var authorNameValue = $authorName.val();
    var bookTitleValue = $bookTitle.val();

    alert(isbnValue);

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "php/getBooks.php",
        dataType: "json",    
        data: {
            isbn: isbnValue
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }

    });
});
```

});

And my PhP code connects to the Database and fetches data based on the query string. Here is my PhP code.

```
<?php
    $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=library;host=localhost';
    // 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDatabase'
    $username = 'root';
    $password = 'maddie';

    $isbnValue = $_GET["isbn"];

    try {
        $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password); // also allows an extra parameter of configuration
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $isbn = $db->quote($isbnValue);
        $rows = $db->query("SELECT isbn, title FROM book WHERE isbn = $isbn");
        $names = array();

        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $names[] = array($row['isbn'], $row['title']);      
        }
        print json_encode($names);

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die('Could not connect to the database:<br/>' . $e);
    }       
?>
```

When I execute from jQuery I get the below error object as response 
Object {readyState: 0, responseText: "", status: 0, statusText: "error"}

Wherease if I directly call the php code using the URL -
http://localhost/LibraryManagement/php/getBooks.php?isbn=970880812

I get the json object as the result. I am not sure where the error is. Any help would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you supplied seems functional. I even tested it locally with jQuery 1.12.1 and had no problems at all.

The error you are receiving is indicative of an ajax call being interrupted before it gets completed. there are many things that can cause this. The most common include cross domain issues and using links or forms actions in concert with your ajax call.

See the following article for more details on this:

http://www.justinball.com/2013/02/25/jqxhr-returning-readystate-0-and-status-0/

A quick google search for:

{readyState: 0, responseText: "", status: 0, statusText: "error"}

will reveal a number of other situations where that can occur as well.

Hope this helps ;)